# The problems overlap dockcontaineritem in Dotnetbar

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetbar

I use many dockcontaineritems of Dotnetbar in  application Windows Form C#.Net.
When i auto hide DockContainerItems then display them. The Dockcontainer items are overlap.
How to fix that ?

Thanks for help me!